# Is there a difference between "to be backed" and "to be back"?

Tags: confusables

This question arises from a sentence in the editorial which I was reading this morning.

> It is understood that Modi will be back in New York on September 28 from San Francisco for a key bilateral meeting.

Should *be back* be *be backed*? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Please quote the entire sentence you encountered.

Comment: It is understood that Modi will be back in New York on September 28 from San Francisco for a key bilateral meeting.

Comment: Have you tried looking up _back_ and _backed_ in a dictionary to see what the difference between them is?

Answer (score 2):

"Back" in the phrase "will be back" is not part of the verb; it's an adverb telling you the manner in which Modi will be in New York, basically he'll  be there again.

"Will be backed" is the future passive form of the verb "to back," which can have several meanings, including "to support."  Thus

> Republican candidates **will be backed** by billionaires, except for
>   Donald Trump who *is* a billionaire, at least by his own accounting.

The two locutions are different and not related, either grammatically or semantically.

Comment: +1, though _back_ isn't an adjective. It can be considered an adverb (more traditionally) or a preposition (more recently, particularly in the _Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_), but not an adjective.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Of course "back" isn't an adjective here.  Thanks.  That should be "adverb," not "adjective," and I've made the correction.  I blame the drugs.  But "back" has its adjectival uses.  It tends to get absorbed, as in words like "backbencher," "backyard," and "backstory."  But it survives on its own in "back teeth" or "back number."